# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.reportviewer.datavisualization

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

We create a WPF project and we add an rdlc report. Add a graph in this report in the old version is working good .we update the version of the report this time the report graph shows some errors.we attached the error given below.[image]

Comment: Try a different solution platform for the project (x86 / x64).

Comment: Like it says. The version matters. Check what you have referenced and supply as the dll against what is targeted.